# Area of a spherical polygon

Tags: differential-geometry, area

A spherical polygon on $S^2$ is the region formed by the intersection of $n$ hemispheres of $S^2$, where $n$ is an integer $\geq 3$.

Show that, if $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n$ are the interior angles of such a polygon, its area is equal to $$\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i − (n − 2)\pi$$

Could you give me some hints how we can show this?

Comment: nice..................+1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a spherical polygon with $n$ sides, we can divide it in $n-2$ adjacent triangles $T_i$ with a common vertex in a vertex (say $C$) of the polygon, such that the area of the polygon $A$ is the sum of the areas $A_i$ of the triangles.

Now, if $a_i,b_i,c_i$ are the internal angles of the triangle $Ti$, the Girard's Theorem states that $a_i+b_i+c_i=\pi+A_i$ where $A_i$ is the area of the triangle.

So, summing for the  $n-2$ triangles, we have:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}\left( a_i+b_i+c_i\right)=(n-2)\pi+\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}A_i
$$

Now it is not difficult to  see that the sum at left is the the sum of all the internal angles of the polygon $\alpha_i$, so that we have:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i=(n-2)\pi+ A
$$

Clearly here the key step is the proof of the Girard's Theorem, that is not difficult , but require a good figure that I'm not able to construct, so I give this [link](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/courses/m308/projects/thomson/Andrew_Thomson-Math_308-Final_Project.ps).

Since you have used the ''differential geometry'' tag, note that the Girard's Theorem is a special case of [Gauss-Bonnet Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem).

---

In this figure the decomposition is illustrated for a plane polygon with $n=6$, decomposed in $n-2=4$ triangles. The figure represents a plane polygon, but for a spherical one the situation is the same. Note that the sum of the internal angles of the triangles gives the sum of the angles of the polygon. A rigorous proof for any $n$ can be given by induction.
[image]

Comment: I haven't really understood why given a spherical polygon with $n$ sides, we can divide it in $n-2$ adjacent triangles $T_i$ with a common vertex in a vertex of the polygon. Could you explain it to me?

Comment: @MaryStar: I've added a figure to my answer. Not  spherical ( too tiring to build) but I hope it can be usefull :)

Comment: So we get $n-2$ **spherical** triangles, right? So do we get these triangles by connecting the one vertex of the polygon with all the others by an arc of
great circles? $$$$ Btw... I wish you a Happy New Year!! :-)

Comment: Yes!...Thank you and happy 2016 to you also.:)

Comment: I see... Thank you so much!! :-)